# DataTables Javascript Library - Headers Not Lining Up - Data Shifting

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I'm using the [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) javascript library to display data.

When the search returns a lot of data, it seems to work okay.

If you stretch the window out far enough, it won't actually line up properly, but it's "usable" for the most part.

[image: Working]

Unfortunately, when it doesn't return much data, the center data shifts as seen here:

[image: Glitched]

I sort of managed to get it to work in the past by setting `bAutoWidth` to false, but then it broke the headers when more data was returned -_-

I've been fighting this for weeks, so any help would be appreciated.

Initialization code:

```
dtTable = $("#CompletedSitesTable").DataTable({
    "scrollY": "50vh",
    "scrollX": "auto",
    "paging": true,
    "pageLength": 100,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "order": [[ 7, "asc" ]],
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel',
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't sure I would get much response from this, but what I did was completely hacky.

On `fnInitComplete` I simply check to see if the datatable has a scrollbar and, if not, I set the width of the div to the width of the headers.

I guess you would change `#resultsDiv` to whatever your wrapper div was and

Function to check for scroll bar:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The `fnInitComplete` code.

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
    if(!$(".dataTables_scrollBody").hasScrollBar())
        $("#resultsDiv").css({ "max-width": $(".dataTable").width()});  
}
```

I guess this will get left like this for now - seems really dumb.